# как исправить ошибку с vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
import vk_api
import random
import time
import datetime

token = "токен"
vk_api = vk_api.vk_api() (token = token)
```

(в последней строке выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable)
> vk_api()

Answer (score 0):

```
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
```

`token=token` надо в скобки убрать, как сделал я